# Qt C++ QComboBox Palette - установка цвета (background-color)

Tags: c++, qt5, виджет

Как без использования `styleSheet` изменить background-color `QComboBox` ?
Используя вот такой код:

```
QComboBox *cmb = new QComboBox(this);

    QPalette palette = cmb->palette();
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::red);
    cmb->setPalette(palette);

    QPalette view_palette = cmb->view()->palette();
    view_palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::red);
    cmb->view()->setPalette(view_palette);

    cmb->addItem("1");
    cmb->addItem("2");
    cmb->addItem("2");
```

Получаю следующий результат: выпадающий список цвет изменяет на красный, но кнопка comboBox остаётся стандартного цвета - как изменить цвет comboBox полностью? (Прикрепляю скриншот текущего результата)
[image: Скриншот 1][image: Скриншот 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmb->setEditable(true);
QLineEdit* lineEdit = cmb->lineEdit();
QPalette palette = lineEdit->palette();
palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::red);
lineEdit->setPalette(palette);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это решает мою проблему.